# Typescript infers return types of methods generated by openapi-generator as Promise<any>

Tags: typescript, axios, openapi-generator

Here is the output of swagger petstore example API passed through openapi-generator (`docker run --rm -it --name openapi-gen -v "$(pwd)":/mnt/workdir -w /mnt/workdir openapitools/openapi-generator-cli generate -i petstore.yaml -g typescript-axios`):
[image]
Note the resulting type is `Promise<any>`.

However if I split it into multiple statements then the return type is inferred (almost) correctly as `Promise<AxiosPromise<User>>`:
[image]

Obviously I'm not going to manually fix every method and it must be working for everyone else. How do I make it work with chained calls generated by `openapi-generator`?

*Extra points for a hint on how to tell typescript that `await AxiosPromise<T>` is just `T`.

Answer (score 0):

Are you missing `axios` in your project, or are you maybe using a version that doesn't match? I encountered this kind of behaviour before in such cases.

If I install the latest version of `axios` (1.2.2) in my generated project, TypeScript infers the type of `UserApi.getUserByName` as `Promise<AxiosResponse<User, any>>`.

If that does not work, you might be able to figure out your problem by checking out the [build examples provided by openapi-generator](https://github.com/OpenAPITools/openapi-generator/tree/v6.2.1/samples/client/petstore/typescript-axios/builds). The [npm-with-version](https://github.com/OpenAPITools/openapi-generator/tree/v6.2.1/samples/client/petstore/typescript-axios/builds/with-npm-version) build is close to what I use.

If all else fails, please share a reproducible setup.

Finally, on `await AxiosPromise<T>`: This should resolve to `AxiosResponse<T, any>` (or `AxiosResponse<T>` for older versions of `axios`), not just `T`. This does work properly in the npm-with-version example linked above as well.